# How to filter out only positive values in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I've got an InfluxDB database with measurements of Grid power usage. The Grid power is negative when our Solar PV is not enough to power up the house and we are *importing* from the grid. Likewise it's the measurement is positive when we've got surplus Solar PV power and we are *exporting* to the grid.

[image: Power grid import export]

Now I would like to calculate (perhaps using `integral()`) the cost of power exported, separately from the cost of power imported. Because there are different rates I can't simply integrate the it all together, I need the above zero and below zero considered separately to calculate the energy in `kWh` and subsequently the cost in each direction.

I was hoping to use InfluxDB `min()` and `max()` but that seem to select the min/max value from a given interval, not quite what I need I think.

Can I somehow split this measurement into two for further calculations?

I'm on InfluxDB 1.8 but considering an upgrade to 2.x eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are going to upgrade to 2.x, you could try Flux.

In v1.8, you can turn on Flux following [this doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/flux/installation/).

Use the [filter operator](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/filter/) to filter the positive and negative values, then apply the [integral function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/integral/).

Power Surplus:

```
from(bucket: "yourDatabaseName/autogen")
    |> range(start: -1h)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "yourMeasurementName" and r._field == "yourFieldName")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value > 0)
    |> integral(unit: 10s)
```

Power Deficit:

```
 from(bucket: "yourDatabaseName/autogen")
    |> range(start: -1h)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "yourMeasurementName" and r._field == "yourFieldName")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value < 0)
    |> integral(unit: 10s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task and just use a nested query in influxdb where I filter only for positive and negative values and then integrate those values.
Just make sure, that your time-interval of the subquery fits to your raw data as we are overwriting missing data points with the fill value "0".
Because due to the subquery you split your data points and thus results in a lot of missing data if you just keep the upper or lower half of it.

This is the query I use for only the positive values.
My shelly power meter sends data every 3-4 seconds, so a grouping by every 5 seconds works well. If you have unstable connection with missing datapoints, better use higher values like 15s or even 30s.
The outer query that integrates and displays the values will be grouped by every hour.

```
SELECT integral("power_from_subquery")  / 3600 AS "Netzbezug" FROM
(SELECT mean("total_act_power") AS "power_from_subquery" FROM "autogen"."shelly" WHERE ("reading"::tag = 'em:0' AND "total_act_power" > 0)  GROUP BY time(5s) fill(0))
WHERE  time >= 1687039200000ms and time <= 1687125599999ms GROUP BY time(1h) tz('Europe/Vienna')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was trying to find a solution for exactly this same problem since a long time.